# Electronic band structures

Tags: schroedinger-equation, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, education, electronic-band-theory

I am looking for step-by-step, clear, detailed and rigorous explanations of methodologies to calculate electronic bands of semiconductor, GaAs as an example, by solving the Schrödinger equation with the k.p method. Everything I could find so far assumes some degree of prerequisite knowledge. Any advice on readings?

Answer (score 0):

People often get annoyed when somebody cites wikipedia, but I would like to point out its less known feature: articles have references, which are often worth exploring. Though here, predictably, one of the main references is the Kittel's book. I suppose that there are more in depth treatments devoted to this subject, but it is worth noting that band structure calculations is a topic that is a) old, b) highly complex, and c) very material-specific (so one might have turn to research literature rather than books).

Comment: I’d go Ashcroft and Mermin over Kittel, but going back to Cardona’s papers in the 60s is a good starting place for literature.